# How to set auto selected option in drop-down with current time?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a drop-down with option SHIFT C, SHIFT A and SHIFT B. I want SHIFT to be auto selected with current time.

Options:

1. Shift-C if time is between 12:00 AM - 07:59 AM
2. Shift-A if time is between 08:00 AM - 03:59 PM
3. Shift-A if time is between 04:00 PM - 11:59 PM

Please help.

```
time = new Date(); 
var hh = time.getHours(); 
var mm = time.getMinutes(); 
var ss = time.getSeconds(); 
var times=hh + ":" + mm + ":" + ss; 
var test=$("#myselect option[value=10]"); 

if($("#myselect option[value=10]")==test) { 
  $("#myselect option[value=3]").attr('selected', 'selected'); 
}
```

Comment: What you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a solution with pure Javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<select id="shift" value="Shift A">
  <option value="Shift A">Shift A</option>
  <option value="Shift B">Shift B</option>
  <option value="Shift C">Shift C</option>
</select>
  <script>
      var today = new Date();
      var hours = today.getHours();
      var value = hours < 8 ? 'Shift A' : hours < 16 ? 'Shift B' : 'Shift C';
      document.getElementById('shift').value = value;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```